# Android Studio Emulator Error - finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, debugging, gradle

So I have an app I've been developing / testing for a bit now and have had no problems at all loading it onto my phone for debug. One day out of nowhere it started throwing and error and wouldn't let me run the emulator anymore. The error is below:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

The gradle console outputs the following error:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","position":           {},"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex   files define Lbolts/AggregateException;","position":  {},"original":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define    Lbolts/AggregateException;"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)","position"     :{},"original":"\tat  com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)","position": {},"original":"\tat   com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat  com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)","position": {},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat   com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","position":{},"original":"\tat   com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)"}
```

I've searched this exact error in a few cases on SO as well as google but none of the solutions seem to work here. I've attached my build.gralde file below as well.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "****"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
```

Anyone can give me a little bit of help here?

Comment: If you launch this gradle task via a console (or a gradle panel), does it give you more information on the reason of the failure?

Comment: Solved - I had to comment out one of my dependencies in the build.gradle file

Comment: please post your solution as an answer and accept it then

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was solved by cleaning the project and removing some unused libraries from dependencies in build.gradle.

If you have to keep libraries then you can enable multi dex by adding in default config.

```
defaultConfig 
{        
    // Enabling multidex support.

    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: multiDexEnabled  ? I don't want wait 1 min to comile ;) not is a good solution

Comment: This solution was working for me .If you have  optimal solution please provide us .Thanks for commment

Answer (score 0):

> *SOLUTION by user3803709 taken from the question*
>
> I had to comment out the following in my build.gradle
>
> ```
> dependencies {
> compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
> //compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+' *commented out*
> compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
> ```